# Displaying articles (objects) in multiple pages

Tags: express, pug

I'm learning Express and Pug and having trouble displaying content on multiple pages.

Using a form I'm creating an article that saves the title + content to a database. Using this code I'm rendering the articles to a "View All Articles" page.

```
// Display list of all articles.
exports.article_list = function (req, res, next) {
  Article.find({}, "title author")
    .sort({ title: 1 })
    .populate("author")
    .exec(function (err, list_articles) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      //Successful, so render
      res.render("article_list", {
        title: "Article List",
        article_list: list_articles,
      });
    });
};
```

Inside my `article_list` `pug` file I have this code which displays a list of all articles.

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title

  ul
    each article in article_list
      li
        a(href=article.url) #{article.title}
        |  by Adam

    else
      li There are no articles.
```

However, when I add the same code to my `index` `pug` file I get the following error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

Not only do I want the articles to be displayed in the "View All Articles" section but I would like the top 5 or 10 most recent submissions to be displayed on the main page but having trouble doing so.

Comment: One situation where this error message is issued is when Pug is trying to iterate through a list type object that is empty, ie `undefined`. I would check that `article_list` is not empty. Add this line: `- console.log(article_list.length);` above `each article...` with the same indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `article_list` is undefined or not an array.

It is not wrong to set a condition here, so that it does not come to an error in pug:

```
- console.log(article_list)

if article_list
    ul
        each article in article_list
```

And also try additional return statements:

```
exports.article_list = function (req, res, next) {
  return Article.find({}, "title author")
    ...
      return res.render("article_list", {
        ...
```